# Sorting and reordering in r

Tags: r, sqldf, levels

I have a dataframe consisting of 96321 observatipns of 11 variables. This data is confidential so I am not able to share it with you. Although I am sharing some screenshot of my data.

[image]

My focus is on the FY and OM variables.

```
levels(mydata$FY)
[1] "2010/11" "2011/12" "2012/13" "2013/14" "2014/15" "2015/16"

levels(mydata$OM)
 [1] "Apr" "Aug" "Dec" "Feb" "Jan" "Jul" "Jun" "Mar" "May" "Nov" "Oct" "Sep"
```

I just want to re-arrange the levels of the 'OM' variable as I want to start my year from April to March (financial Year).

I used the following command to rearrange the levels of my 'OM' variables:

```
table(is.na(mydata$OM))

    FALSE 
    96321



 levels(mydata$OM)<-c('Apr','May','Jun','July','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec','Jan','Feb','Mar'
                               )



table(is.na(mydata$OM)) #NO NA is introduced

        FALSE 
        96321


 levels(mydata$OM)
     [1] "Apr"  "May"  "Jun"  "July" "Aug"  "Sep"  "Oct"  "Nov"  "Dec"  "Jan"  "Feb"  "Mar"
```

I got the result as I expected but when I tried to arrange my data sorted by the 'OM' variable using sql I am not getting the desired result.

```
sortedData <-sqldf('SELECT * FROM mydata
             ORDER BY OM ASC')
```

I expected the result in increasing order of levels of 'OM' variable like Apr first then May and then Mar in the last. But the order is somewhat distorted. Please help me on this.

Note:- I also tried

```
mydata$OM <- factor(mydata$OM, levels = c('Apr','May','Jun','July','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec','Jan','Feb','Mar'
))

mydata$OM <-factor(mydata$OM, levels = c('Apr','May','Jun','July','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec',
                                         'Jan','Feb','Mar'),
                              labels = c('Apr','May','Jun','July','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec',
                                         'Jan','Feb','Mar'))
```

But these introduced NA in the result.

```
table(is.na(mydata$OM))

FALSE  TRUE 
88097  8224
```

Comment: Your original data contains "Jul" but when you set the levels you set it equal to "July". I think you are using `levels <- ` the wrong way, what you need is to use `factor(mydata$OM, levels = c(...))`.

Answer (score 1):

```
mydata$OM <- factor(mydata$OM, levels = c('Apr','May','Jun','July','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec','Jan','Feb','Mar'
                               ))
```

Comment: It is introducing NA in my results .table(is.na(sortedData$OM))

FALSE  TRUE 
88097  8224

Comment: The problem is that you are using sql to sort the factor but sql is sorting according to the alphabetical order of the OM variable. I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mydata[order(mydata$OM),]`
This will solve your problem. In case of Multiple sorting use

```
mydata[order(mydata$OM,mydata$FY),]
```